# set off a secondary line of code when button is pressed in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm building a log in screen, I got most of the code done, now I need to simply be able to set off a secondary window when the log in button completes a successful function.

here's the code:

```
 def log():
    global us_name, log_pass, hash1, profile_logged, log_complete
    us_name = entrylogun.get()
    log_pass = entrylogpa.get()
    hash1 = pbkdf2_sha256.hash(str(log_pass), rounds=1, salt_size=0)
    log_pass = 0
    log_complete = False
    with open("users.txt", "r") as users:
        if (us_name + "" + hash1 + "") in users.read():
            log_complete = True
            profile_logged = open("" + us_name + ".txt", "r+")
        else:
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Verification Error",
                                        "The Password and Username combination \n entered is not valid, please try again")
    return log_complete
```

after that i have all my GUI set up, then the log in button set up

```
register_button = Button(center_frame, padx=7, pady=2, text="Log In", font=("arial", 10), bg="light grey", fg="black", command= (log and ))
register_button.grid(row=17, pady=8)
```

Now, i'm trying that once that button is pressed after all the log in checks completed successfully, launch a new window. However, I cannot get to launch all of that code only when the log in is successful... i'm lost to how i can. I have already looked everywhere and seriously cannot find how...

if I simply start a new string dependent on log_complete, python makes me set that variable from the get go and because i need to define it before hand, it runs it beforehand, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need another function that runs your function that launches a new window if and only if `log()` returns `True`.

The are two ways to do this: you can either define a new named function, or use a lambda expression.

(I am assuming you have a function `launch` that requires no arguments and launches your new window.)

#### Defining a new function

```py
def fred(): # I can't think of a good name right now
    if log():
        launch()
```

You can then pass `fred` to the `Button` constructor like any other function.

This is rather verbose for a function you will (probably) only use once.

#### [Lambda expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda)

```py
lambda: launch() if log() else False
```

This lambda expression uses a conditional expression to evaluate `launch()` if `log()` returns `True` and returns `False` otherwise. (The `False` is irrelevant in this case because the return value of `Button`'s `command` function is not used anywhere. It is only here because conditional expressions require something to evaluate if the condition evaluates to `False`.)

You can pass this lambda expression to the `Button` constructor like any other function:

```py
register_button = Button(center_frame, padx=7, pady=2, text="Log In", font=("arial", 10), bg="light grey", fg="black", command=lambda: launch() if log() else False)
```